# Edit Pop-ups on QlikView Chart

Tags: qlikview

I have an expression `Sum of Cycle Times` in a bar chart. I want to display the equation used to calculate the value of the expression when I hover over the bar in the chart. Right now, the pop-up box displays the dimension value and the expression value. Can I edit what is displayed in the pop-up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new expression with your expression formula in quotes and set it to 'Text as Pop-up'. This is a common practice in Qlikview charts as a means to get custom pop-up text. It's still not a perfect solution, but it will take care of your problem.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I need. However, I have multiple expressions already, so I want to display different equations on each bar in each dimension (i.e. March has `sum_cycle_time` and `avg_cycle_time`). Is there a way to display different equations on different bars?

Comment: In order to do that, you can either hard code the specific months (dimension values) into the expression via a [set expression](https://community.qlik.com/blogs/qlikviewdesignblog/2015/02/16/set-analysis) if you want to display the value, OR, you can drop it in an if condition if you're just displaying your expression formula as text. So using the first method: `=sum({$<month={'March','June','September','December'}>} sales)` or method two: `if(month = 'March' or month = 'June' etc... , 'your expression formula')`.